# Under standing Update Queries, and how many sets one query can have

Tags: mysql

So Dumb question, I'm try to execute this really complex UPDATE query. From the way that the UPDATE syntax is set up; is it possible, and is it wise to have multiple SET keywords in the query.

this is for a form, that holds a 2-d array of information, that is populated from the database. Each row of the array is equivalent to a record in the database. On submit, the query should be updating the table values.

```
<form>
<p>Item 1</p><input name='itemID1'><input name='ItemDescr1'><input name='itemCost1'>
<p>Item 2</p><input name='itemID2'><input name='ItemDescr2'><input name='itemCost2'>
<p>Item 3</p><input name='itemID3'><input name='ItemDescr3'><input name='itemCost3'>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

This is a new kind of query that i have attempted, and i'm kind of lost as how far SQL is capable of handling such a query.  But this is how I imagine the query should be structured

i.e.

```
UPDATE table SET (col1 = "value1", col2= "value2",...) WHERE idcol = "ID1", 
SET (col1 = "value3", col2= "value4",...) WHERE idcol = "ID2"
```

I really don't know if this would work, or if it should be done. If there are people in the industry that have encountered this problem, please help.

Comment: Is it because you feel running it in one go gives you consistency in case your update fails? Did you look into transactions already, so that you can just send multiple update commands and then commit in the end?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the reason i want to try and get it in one update query, or at least try to have a loop and query structure setup like this, is because in my actual application, the user has more control over the form length, and how many records they want to add. So I want the query creation to be flexible for this sake.

Comment: But then again, transaction might be a more useful way to go at this, at least you know that all of them have worked, before comitting the changes to the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably better off just writing separate UPDATE queries for each one; with the syntax you are envisioning you're only an "UPDATE table" away already.... but if you're in one of those odd situations where your number of queries are limited you *can* do this (**I would not suggest it unless there are extenuating circumstances as it makes the query unnecessarily complicated, and probably actually slower**).

```
UPDATE table 
SET col1 = CASE idcol WHEN "ID1" THEN "value1" WHEN "ID2" THEN "value3" ..... ELSE col1 END
    , col2 = CASE idcol WHEN "ID1" THEN "value2" WHEN "ID2" THEN "value4" ..... ELSE col2 END
WHERE idCol IN ("ID1", "ID2", ....)
;
```

The ELSE should not be necessary unless you forget the WHERE clause, or change the WHERE's IN list without updating all those CASE expressions accordingly; in which case it will prevent the query from inadvertently NULLing a bunch of data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So If I am understanding this correctly; I would go through each column, and assign each value based on the ID I'm trying to associate it with?

Comment: So if I were to loop it in php would it be like.
$query=" UPDATE table SET";
if ($_POST[ID~] != ""){
$query .= "
 col1 = Case idcol WHEN ".$_POST['ID1']." THEN "$_POST['val1']" When ...
....
";
}
Do I have this right?

Comment: I'm not great with php or web stuff in general, for example I am not sure if that `~` does something special, but basically you'd need to replace all the quoted bits with your data.

Comment: I'd still lean towards icepickle's recommendation of beginning a transaction, looping through the multiple updates, and then committing them.